# Event binding using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display city options based on State selected, where states are dynamically loaded according to selected country (country list is static). but the problem is my action page which receives the data from ajax is not receiving any value for state. This is my first try for event binding so please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#country').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "state_selector_db.php",
      method: "post",
      data: {
        "country": value
      },
      success: function(result) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result)
        $('div#state').html(obj.state);
      }
    });
  });
  $('body').on("change", function() {
    var value2 = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "state_selector_db.php",
      method: "post",
      data: {
        "state": value2
      },
      success: function(res) {
        var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(res)
        $('div#city').html(obj2.city);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>Country:&nbsp</b>
</p>
<select id="country">
  <option value="na">Select</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  <option value="england">England</option>
</select>
<div id="state"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
```

Comment: Need to see HTML code also.

Comment: Did you check if the php script you're sending the request to sends the correct data as valid JSON?

Comment: Actually, using $('body').change, you're directly refering to the body. Despite it might be working, the $(this) should then refere to the body, rather than an input change, shouldn't it?

Comment: `$('body').on("change"` doesn't look right!

Comment: @LShetty: It looks fine, see [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler). The `selector` and `data` are optional.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl lol ;) I knew that for a long time now. What I meant is, `change` event is for form elements and doesn't fire when _HTML_ changes!

Comment: @MildlySerious I think there is no error in that php script since it sends correct data for state options and even send the correct for second condition that is when no result found for city options. it always senda that there is no city since state value is blank

Comment: @LShetty yes, and the below accepted answer worked, thanks to all for their effort and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track but you will need a little change in event binding

to bind events to select element that you have populated after ajax use following. change event is of select.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on("change", "div#state select", function () {
        var value2 = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "state_selector_db.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {
                "state": value2
            },
            success: function (res) {
                var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(res)
                $('div#city').html(obj2.city);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this following addition:

```
$('body').on("change", "#state", function () {
                       ^^^^^^^^
```